# Google Charts: Get element from selected bar in histogram

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I created histogram and populated it with such data :

```
[
 ['Name of test', 'Runtime of test'],
 ['Foo', 123],
 ...
]
```

I am trying to get all items from selected bar of histogram using `chart.getSelection()`. But I am getting only this for selected bar which contains more than 100 elements.

```
 Array[1]
   0: Object
     column: 1
     row: 0
     ...
   length: 1
```

Does it possible get any useful data from getSelection for Google Histogram, I mean data like selected interval at least?

Answer (score 0):

the `'select'` [event](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/histogram#events) provides the `row` and `column` of the data selected

use those values to pull data, from the DataTable used to draw the chart

*note:* the `'select'` event fires both when something is *selected* AND *un-selected*

be sure to check the `length` before trying to access the contents of the selection array
(the array will be empty when something is *un-selected*)

it appears only only one row at a time can be selected

and `column` is only needed if you have more than one series

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Dinosaur', 'Length'],
    ['Acrocanthosaurus (top-spined lizard)', 12.2],
    ['Albertosaurus (Alberta lizard)', 9.1],
    ['Allosaurus (other lizard)', 12.2],
    ['Apatosaurus (deceptive lizard)', 22.9],
    ['Archaeopteryx (ancient wing)', 0.9],
    ['Argentinosaurus (Argentina lizard)', 36.6],
    ['Baryonyx (heavy claws)', 9.1],
    ['Brachiosaurus (arm lizard)', 30.5],
    ['Ceratosaurus (horned lizard)', 6.1],
    ['Coelophysis (hollow form)', 2.7],
    ['Compsognathus (elegant jaw)', 0.9],
    ['Deinonychus (terrible claw)', 2.7],
    ['Diplodocus (double beam)', 27.1],
    ['Dromicelomimus (emu mimic)', 3.4],
    ['Gallimimus (fowl mimic)', 5.5],
    ['Mamenchisaurus (Mamenchi lizard)', 21.0],
    ['Megalosaurus (big lizard)', 7.9],
    ['Microvenator (small hunter)', 1.2],
    ['Ornithomimus (bird mimic)', 4.6],
    ['Oviraptor (egg robber)', 1.5],
    ['Plateosaurus (flat lizard)', 7.9],
    ['Sauronithoides (narrow-clawed lizard)', 2.0],
    ['Seismosaurus (tremor lizard)', 45.7],
    ['Spinosaurus (spiny lizard)', 12.2],
    ['Supersaurus (super lizard)', 30.5],
    ['Tyrannosaurus (tyrant lizard)', 15.2],
    ['Ultrasaurus (ultra lizard)', 30.5],
    ['Velociraptor (swift robber)', 1.8]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Lengths of dinosaurs, in meters',
    legend: { position: 'none' },
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.Histogram(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
    var selection = chart.getSelection();
    if (selection.length) {
      var dinosaur = data.getValue(selection[0].row, 0);
      var dinosaurLength = data.getValue(selection[0].row, selection[0].column);
      console.log(dinosaur + ': ' + dinosaurLength);
    }
  });
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
 google.visualization.events.addListener(_this.chart, 'click', clickHandler);

    function clickHandler(e) {
        if (e.targetID !== 'chart') {
            var cli = _this.chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
            var bBox = cli.getBoundingBox(e.targetID);

            var minValue = Math.ceil(cli.getHAxisValue(bBox.left));
            var maxValue = Math.round(cli.getHAxisValue(bBox.left + bBox.width));

        }
    }
```